# Android: Source path not being included

Tags: android, build

In my project I have added some folders that I want included in my project for source files. But no matter what I do, the source never gets recognized. I tried refreshing, clean up, restarting but nothing works. Here is the project's source folder:

[image: Project source folder]

I want the folders integration/android added. This is how it is showing up in Eclipse:

[image: Eclipse folders]

And here is what my build configuration looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but it looks like you have added them as a folder, but not actually added the folder to your project.

The folder should show up in your src folder in the solution explorer window under your other package.

Try creating the package name in your project, then move all the src files into it.

And when its in the src folder, in its correct package, you dont need to include any extra build paths.

(You can have multiple packages in a single application)

Answer (score 0):

Importing someone elses project that is over 2 years old is almost always problematic. I found the easiest solution just to create a fresh project and add the files manually from the old project.